# Asmack Conflict(409) - when trying to login to server

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am getting conflict error(409) while trying to connect to Openfire server.

I checked with the server, and the server policy is set to "kick last connection if any same new incoming connection"

```
W/System.err(13238): conflict(409)
W/System.err(13238):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.bindResourc
eAndEstablishSession(SASLAuthentication.java:458)
W/System.err(13238):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticat
e(SASLAuthentication.java:349)
W/System.err(13238):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConne
ction.java:230)
W/System.err(13238):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.ja
va:353)
```

when trying to do this:

```
ConnectionConfiguration xmppCc = new ConnectionConfiguration("some.domain");
xmppCc.setSendPresence(false);
XMPPConnection xmppConn = new XMPPConnection(xmppCc);
xmppConn.connect();
xmppConn.login(username, password);
```

the exception is thrown when executing the last row (login)

I do this on my activity onDestroy()

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
    xmppConn.sendPacket(presence);  
    xmppConn.disconnect();
}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks! :D

Comment: What happens if you try to log in using a different resource?

Comment: I can login successfully, same thing if I use this resource on the first try, after I successfully login, I just can't login again, it throws the error above..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't search the code within smack. It seems like the server (sounds like openfire) isn't doing what you configured him to do: Kicking the last resource. You could try to verify this case by using an XMPP client which tries to bind an already connected fullJID (that's bare ID + resource).

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't really understand what you mean by "You could try to verify this case by using an XMPP client which tries to bind an already connected fullJID (that's bare ID + resource)" can you provide me with a name of the client that do this?
I tried to login using pidgin (windows platform) and it logs in and out without any problems, and I try logging in with another client (citron IM) while the pidgin still logging in, they both login successfully (two connections at the same time)

Comment: The idea is that you reproduce the situation with a different XMPP client/library with the same server to see if behavior stays the same, so that you can rule out smack as the problem. Do they both login with the same full JID?

Answer (score 0):

@GodWin  xmpp through the  conflict error(409) when you create an account with a username which is already taken by any other. At Login time Xmpp not through this type of exception.
So if you create an account then use new credential which is not register on server.